# And/Or and Except/Only

Tags: word-choice, differences, is-it-a-rule

I have the following sentence:

> Who am I? Picture James Bond, except without the British Accent. Or the six-pack.

My question is about two words: *except* versus *only*; also, *or* versus *and*.

Seems like *or* and *and* have the same meaning here. Which is better? Is there a rule?

Same goes with *except* and *only*: is one better that they other, and is there a rule about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the basics is always a good start:

- **Only** is an adverb (long story short: **only** can accompany **except** as an option).
- **Except** can be a preposition (before a noun) or a conjunction.
- **Or** & **and** are conjunctions that are *mutually exclusive*. (in your case, *or* is used to cope with *without* - negation)

[Breakdown]
In general, try reforming your sentences into simpler chunks to get a better sense.

> "1. <s>except</s> without the British Accent" *OR* 2. "*only* except <s>without</s> the British Accent"

1. "except" is unnecessary here.
2. If you choose to keep "except," you *may* precede it with "only" as an emphasis. However, this is most relevant when there is a single condition. In fact, using "only" with "or" causes confusion (`I only lack the British Accent or the six-pack.` In this case, it gives "either/or" nuance.)

---

[Answer] With those two pieces in mind,

### the revision:

> "Who am I? Picture James Bond, without the British Accent or the six-pack."

Just for fun, you could also say this:

> "Who is James Bond? Picture `@ygoncho`, except he has British Accent and six-pack."

Comment: Can't upvote because I don't have enough rep, but thanks a lot!

Comment: @ygoncho In case it wasn't clear, you may combine `only` with __without__ as well (under part 1). @KarlRookey has a more in-depth analysis if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example text, the word `except` is used as a conjunction and it *could* be replaced by the conjunction `only` — as you suggest — with very little change in meaning. The difference is nuanced and a matter of preference. So it is your choice:

> "Picture James Bond, **except** without the British Accent."
>   
>   OR
>   
>   "Picture James Bond, **only** without the British Accent."

Your second question, about `and` / `or` is harder to answer. Because the two words have very different meanings (as noted by Crosscounter), it is usually easy to decide between them: do I want *both* (cookies **and** milk) or do I want *one* (cookies **or** milk)?

In the text you are examining, there is nothing so concrete to guide us, since I am *without* the items described. This may be another matter of preference, but I have a strong feeling that `or` is better.  I cannot find a rule to support my preference, but here's my logic:

In English usage, there are word pairs that belong together, called correlatives.  These include *both—and* / *either—or* / *neither—nor*. It seems to me if you use `and` you imply the word `both`, and if you use the word `or` you imply the word `either`. When I ask myself if it should be "without either a British accent or a six-pack" or "without both a British accent and a six-pack", the word `either` emerges the clear winner.

So, with the understanding that my logic may be flawed, and this may actually be a matter of preference, the word `or` is preferred:

> "Picture James Bond, except without the British accent. **Or** the six-pack"
>   
>   NOT
>   
>   "Picture James Bond, except without the British accent. **And** the six-pack"

Comment: Initially, using `or` seemed counter-intuitive. In my head, I kept thinking "not having a British accent won't _undo_ a six-pack" but reading your point about correlatives adds to the reasoning and clarity. In order to enable {and}, it would be "lacking/minus both the accent `and` the six-pack."